# How to show the totall amount of process ,main memory, virtual memory usage in SYSTEMTAP?

Tags: linux, memory-management, systemtap

I wanna write a script that monitors one (selected) item component for the following operating systems:

- Process Management
- Management of main memory
- Virtual memory management
- Management of input / output
- Network Management

and I came up with this idea how to show it:

```
   process | main memory | virtual memory | input/output |  network
  % usage  |  % usage    |     % usage    |     ???      | data send/recived
```

I don't know how to show % usage of CPU, main memory, and virtual memory.
Also I don't know what to manage in input/output.

Answer (score 2):

Systemtap is better suited to monitoring **events** rather than **levels** like some of those.  Consider using something like PCP (http://oss.sgi.com/projects/pcp) for simple periodic level monitoring.

Comment: ok but I have to monitor one (selected) item component for the following operating systems in Systemtap. So  this % usage is stupid idea right?